# NullPointerException on CursorAdapter bindView method

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I created a class extending CursorAdapter, i am having problem on the bindView method.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {


    int colNum = c.getColumnIndex(VidCallDbAdapter.QRLINK);
    String colValue = c.getString(colNum);

    System.out.println("value>> " + colValue);

    TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qr_url);

    name_text.setText(colValue);

}
```

im always getting a NullPointerException in this line

TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qr_url);

It's weird because i defined qr_url on one of my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text=""   
          android:id="@+id/qr_url" 
          android:gravity="center_vertical" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:textColor="#000000" 
          android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Did i miss something on the code that's why it's a NullPointerException? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your `newView(View,Context,Cursor)` also

Comment: oww it's related to it. i returned null to that method because im having exception on my method. that explains the NullPointerException. Thanks.  But my original code for that method is @Override
 public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
//  return null;
 }

i'm having exception on the line with return

Comment: how is `layout` defined? check my edit

Comment: which edit? layout is defined as layout = R.layout.list_layout_qrurl; on the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting `NullPointerException` in this line

```
TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qr_url);
```

it means that `v` is null, cause if TextView is not found `null` would be returned and `NullPointerException` would be thrown in

```
name_text.setText(colValue);
```

So make sure your `public View newView(...)` is overrided correctly.

**edit** 
what you should return in newView is

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.<name of your xml>, parent, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. i think there is a problem with my public View newView(...) method. i intentionally returned null to that method because i thought that's the solution to the other exception that i encountered. originally my method is: @Override
 public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
//  return null;
 }
but i'm having an exception on the line return... 

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 Would you know the reason for this?

Comment: It means `layout` is 0. you might either set it as `layout = R.layout.<name of your xml, the one you posted in your question>` or as I suggested in my answer just pass R.layout.<name> to `inflater.inflate()`

Comment: you're right. i defined my layout as layout = R.layout.list_layout_qrurl. and now am having a NullPointerException in name_text.setText(colValue); of the bindView method.

Comment: Then either `colValue` or `name_text` is null. If TextView with id `qr_url` is really in `list_layout_qrurl.xml` try `name_text.setText("test")` and see what happens. If it works than there is problem with `colValue`, which is really strange

Comment: I saw the problem. It's on my definition of my layout (stupid mistake :) ) I was able to figure out everything because of your replies. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where **bindView()** was throwing a NullPointerException.  I solved it by calling `setEmptyView()` on my ListView.